# Mongoose Schema Array: CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have following schema and when I am going to update it, I get mentioned exception.

I have seen couple of questions here but still a bit not clear where I am making a mistake.

**Schema**

```
var DishSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  dishes: [ {
    name: { type: String, index: { unique: true } , required:true },
    type: String,
    descdish: String,
    servingtype: String,
    servingquantity: Number,
    cuisine: String,
    features: [ { type: String } ],
    dishphotos: {
      mainphoto: String,
      secphoto: String,
      thirdphoto: String
    },
    price: Number,
    discount: {
      offer: {type: Boolean ,  default: false },
      discoutamount: String,
      from: Date,
      to: Date
    },
    availability: {
      advancebooking: {
        mindish: Number,
        orderby: String
      },
      premake: {
        from: Date,
        to: Date,
        aftertime: String,
        orderby: String,
        quantity: Number
      },
      regulardishes: [
        {
          weekday: String,
          orderby: String,
          readyby: String,
          readyday: String,
          pickfrom: String,
          pickto: String,
          qty: Number
        }
      ]
    }  
  } ] 
});
```

I store values in a var/record like below before executing the mongo statement.

```
  var docId = req.body.userid;
  var query = { user: docId };   

  var dishRecord = {  
    name : req.body.name || "" , 
    type : req.body.type || "",  
    descdish : req.body.descdish || "", 
    servingtype : req.body.servingtype || "", 
    servingquantity : req.body.servingquantity || "", 
    cuisine : req.body.cuisine || "", 
    features : req.body.features || "", 
    dishphotos : req.body.dishphotos || "",        
    price : req.body.price || "", 
    discount : req.body.discount || "",       
    availability : {
      advancebooking :  req.body.availability.advancebooking || "",   
      premake : req.body.availability.premake || "",
      regulardishes : req.body.availability.regulardishes || [] 
    }       
  }
```

then I run

```
Dish.findByIdAndUpdate(
     docId,
     { $push: {"dishes": dishRecord}},
     {  safe: true, upsert: true},
       function(err, model) {
         if(err){
          console.log("Dish DB Error::: ", err);
          return res.send(err);
         }
         console.log( "Dish DB updated");
          return res.json(model);
});
```

**Exception**

```
Dish DB Error::: { [CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "dishes"]
  stack: 'Error\n    at MongooseError.CastError   
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)',
  message: 'Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "dishes"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: undefined,
  value: [{"availability":{"regulardishes":[{"qty":"1","pickto":"","pickfrom":"","readyday":"","readyby":"","orderby":"","weekday":""},{"qty
":"1","pickto":"09:00 AM","pickfrom":"09:00 AM","readyday":"Same day","readyby":"09:00 AM","orderby":"09:00 AM","weekday":"Mon"}],"premake":
{"quantity":"1","orderby":"","aftertime":"","to":"09:00 AM","from":"09:00 AM"},"advancebooking":{"orderby":"12 Hours","mindish":"1"}},"disco
unt":{"to":"30-8-2015","from":"30-8-2015","discoutamount":"10%","offer":false},"price":"","dishphotos":{"thirdphoto":"","secphoto":"","mainp
hoto":""},"features":[],"cuisine":"","servingquantity":"1","servingtype":"","descdish":"","type":"","name":""}],
  path: 'dishes' }
```

Comment: You are trying to put an Object where you defined an Array (`dishes`).

Comment: object at dishes.availability.regulardishes level ?